# Filtering and updating a JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I have the following JSON

> Json

```
{
    "components": {
        "id": "application",
        "actions": [{
            "action": "/show-dashboard",
            "text": {
                "en": "Dashboard",
                "es": "Dashboard-ES"
            }
        }, {
            "action": "/showContact",
            "text": {
                "en": "Personal",
                "es": "Personal-ES"
            }
        }, {
            "action": "/showSummary",
            "text": {
                "en": "Summary",
                "es": "Summary-ES"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

And I need to filter the actions. Only two are possible (this json is smaller the original have more than 20 actions)

So I have a JsObject called components with this json. Then I used this

> Scala

```
    val filteredActions = (components \\ "actions").head.as[List[JsValue]].filter{ _.\("action").as[String] match {
    case "/showContact" => true
    case "/showSummary" => true
    case _ => false
  }}
```

So I have in filteredActions a json string with the actions filtered, now I need to update components and replace the current actions with this one.

I have try this:

> Scala

```
 val jsonTransformer2 = (__ \ 'components \ 'actions).json.update((__ \ 'components).json.put(Json.arr(filteredActions)))

 val filtered = components.transform(jsonTransformer2)
```

But is not working..

Any advice please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Alejandro, which json library are you using?

Comment: I'm using play.api.libs.json._ for scala 2.4

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Does it throw exceptions, or just don't update the payload?

Comment: It's generated a wrong JSON

Answer (score 0):

what results do you expect ?
if you just want to remove action `/show-dashboard` in actions

```
val jsonTransformer2 = (__ \ 'components \ 'actions).json.put(JsArray(filteredActions))
val filtered         = components.transform(jsonTransformer2)
println(filtered.get)
```

// result

```
{
  "components": {
    "actions": [
      {
        "action": "/showContact",
        "text": {
          "en": "Personal",
          "es": "Personal-ES"
        }
      },
      {
        "action": "/showSummary",
        "text": {
          "en": "Summary",
          "es": "Summary-ES"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this is good progress. but I'm losing the id. This is what I'm getting:

> Json

{
    "components": {
        "actions": [{
            "action": "/showContact",
            "text": {
                "en": "Personal",
                "es": "Personal-ES"
            }
        }, {
            "action": "/showSummary",
            "text": {
                "en": "Summary",
                "es": "Summary-ES"
            }
        }]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It really helped me to get a better understand of how this works.

I found the solution.

Just need it to change the transformer to this:

> Scala

```
val jsonTransformer2 = (__ \ 'components \ 'actions).json.update((__ \ 'components \ 'actions).json.put(JsArray(filteredActions)))
```

Again thanks to everyone.